# using akka in scala with maven

Tags: scala, maven, akka

Edit2: this has been resolved; check the comments. my scala version was not in line with akka's package version.

My code compiles fine (and the exact code using sbt works fine), but for my scala project using maven, I get this error when calling `ActorSystem()`:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
    at akka.util.Timeout.<init>(Timeout.scala:13)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:327)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:651)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:244)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:287)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:232)
```

Has anyone else had this issue? Any way around it or do I need to convert to sbt to use akka?

edit: here are the packages I added to my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-testkit_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Consider adding the relevant excerpt from the pom.xml. How are you packaging it?

Comment: Looks like you are running into some sort of version mismatching. What Scala version are you using?

Comment: Maybe more specifically: what `scalaVersion` is the scala-maven-plugin using in your pom.xml, not what `$ scala -version` says in your console.

Comment: yeah it was the scala version. I was using 12.11. When i switched the akka packages to use 2.11 in the artifactId, it works fine. thanks everyone

Comment: Have you imported an implicit timeout variable in the calling code? It could think you're trying to call an initMethod, but if you don't have the Timeout in scope, it's trying to call the method that doesn't take the timeout parameter, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @NateH06 "Scope" is a data structure that is maintained during compilation. This here is not a compilation problem: it's a problem with already compiled and packaged dependencies which try to invoke methods on some non-existent code for the wrong scala-version. You cannot solve something like that by modifying code, you have to adjust your build intstead.